# Highcharts - Include several charts in one container

Tags: highcharts

I tried to search on the forum but didn't find anything about a simple question: How can we include several highcharts in one container as my example? Is it possible ?

[My example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kjmGu.jpg)

Thanks for your answer.

Comment: Why do you want it ? What do you want to do ?

Answer (score 0):

You mean, like [this](http://www.highcharts.com/demo/combo-multi-axes)?

You can set how many series you want at the same chart.

However, to make the "chart grid" like in your image, you have to make 4 div to store each one of your charts

Comment: Not really like the "Combo multi axes". I want to do a chart grid... But seems to be impossible in 1 div.

Comment: @ Felipe => Thank you for your answer. Seems to be impossible to put several charts on one div, so I will try to do it by using one div per one highchart.